# asp.net Core/OnPostAsync: what's the best way to prevent a record from being created twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I'm working with an ASP.Net Core 3.1/EF Core web app.

The issue is with "Create" pages.  The user fills in the Razor web form and hits "Submit".  The server executes OnPostAsync() in "Pages\MyFunction\Create.cshtml.cs".  OnPostAsync(), in turn, doesn't just "SaveChangesAsync()" the posted data.  It queries some other, separate data ("await"), does some computations, and then finally creates the new record. Then exits: return RedirectToPage("./Index");

PROBLEM:

This can take several moments.

The user is still sitting at the "Create" page.

And he/she can hit "Submit" again.  And again.  Creating multiple, duplicate records.

Q: What options do I have that could mitigate this scenario?

Comment: What would you want it to do instead, give an error message?  Is it possible for you to implement the "Post / Redirect / Get" pattern, where the "Get" page polls for the operation to be completed?

Comment: So, databases have these things called primary keys..

Comment: UI feedback?  Disable the Submit button as soon as they click it and change it to a spinner so they know it's working.

Comment: @Bryan Lewis: excellent suggestion - thank you! FOLLOW-ON QUESTION:  I'll probably disable the submit button/show the spinner with jQuery ... but I need to choose a JS event and write the handler such that it WON'T interfere with the OOTB ASP.Net Core/Razor client-side validation (that mix of bootstrap and jquery-validation code that automagically triggers when any of the form elements require client-side validation). Could you post pseudo-code for a solution? I'd be happy to "upvote" whatever you suggest, however "incomplete".

Comment: few suggestions, use async, let end user know, request was submitted, (if there is a page you can redirect user, do that, or disable submit button), make sure your DB uses primary Key, validate before submitted to DB if item does not exist, implement notification to end user when request is done including feedback if item already exists

Comment: @Nonik: thank you. As it happens, I *am* using Async (when I POST the completed form), but certain things need to happen before I "Create" the record and exit "OnPostAsync()".  Hence the problem.  Yes, my EF record *DOES* have a PK ... but (as wise-acre  Caius Jard seems to have forgetten) it's uninitialized before .SaveChangesAsync().  So it doesn't help me distinguish between "the first" and "subsequent, duplicate" requests.  Q: Any other suggestions?  Q: Any ideas about how/where to "disable" the submit button on the client side (in a way that doesn't "break" UX or client side validation)?

Answer (score 1):

You have mainly three options:

1. Optimize the save operation
2. Call the form submission asynchronously
3. Switch to an asynchronous API pattern

## Optimizing the save operation

Well this one is an easy answer. Your operation is long and creates some frustration to your user ? Optimize. Well of course, not all operations are can be made to run so fast users have no frustration. However, this is not an exclusive answer. Perhaps you'll find some interesting options below, that is not a reason to be lazy and skip looking into the code for some performance issues.

## Submitting the form asynchronously

Calling the form asynchronously requires you to prevent the browser from navigating when submitting the form. Instead, use client side code to disable the form and display a progress animation to the user. This will prevent them from submitting the form multiple times. Then asynchronously send an HTTP POST request to the server via XHR. When the operation completes, display a message to the user and/or navigate to the next page. This technique does not require any change in your current server-side implementation, but does not scale up very well. Also, it locks your users into a "please wait" mindset, but sometimes that's actually the most relevant UX.

## Asynchronous API pattern

Asynchronous API pattern is a pattern that changes your server side implementation. After submitting his form, the post query handler only does some fast content validation with the data, and then immediately returns. The server will do the long operation on the background afterwards, and your application must implement a notification system to provide progress information to the user. The notification system can be either polling or pushing.

#### Get/Redirect/Post

The most common implementation of this pattern is the Post/Redirect/Get pattern. The  `OnPostAsync()` method will return a redirect response to the user after the form is validated and the operation is ready to start. That will forward the user to another page that will wait for the task completion. It's easy to implement but does not provide an excellent user experience.

#### Page load notification system

In this approach we add a notification system to every page in the application (usually in a sort of master template). This component will look for messages to display to the user, and insert them in the document. When the user submit its form (either via navigation or XHR), only do some fast validation and return. You can add a message to confirm the operation successfully started. Begin the background operation and when complete, add a message to the user. While navigating, the user will eventually get notified his operation succeeded or failed.

#### Notification endpoint

Another solution is to implement a small API that allows clients to query long running operations status. Whenever the user has a running task in the pool, add some code to the client that will periodically call that endpoint for operation progress. Use that information to display notifications, or if motivated (and if the process allows easy progress percentage computation), you can even display progress bars that fill up during the process. Then update your server-side operation to provide frequent progress information to the notification system. If combined with XHR form submit, users can start and complete long running operations without any navigation.

#### Push notification

This technique requires some modern technology, such as SignalR, but will provide the best performance and user experience. First, the application will establish a duplex communication with the server. Now, the server is able to stream messages to the client directly. Clients don't need to spend most of their resources polling the server any more, they just send their forms content. The server doesn't need to scale up in order to reply to millions of users that nothing changed since the last second, it only need to handle form submits. Also, you don't need to wait for the user to poll the server in order to provide him feedback. You can do that real time.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions.  But I don't want to do any XHR or any polling.  I just want to be able to submit the "Create" form and prevent the user from impatiently hitting "submit" multiple times.  Since my entity's IDs are auto-generated, I can't use Primary key (it doesn't exist yet).  Maybe I can simply disable the "submit" button.  But I don't know if this might interfere with the OOTB "client-side validation".

Comment: I don't remember having had problems with disabling the submit button. It should work.

Comment: Also, even if you don't have the entity key, you can create an id for the operation. That can be used to obtain asynchronously the db generated primary key of the entity at a later stage. This implies a more complex navigation behavior though.